# Is it possible to avoid pipes when reading from mysql in bash

Tags: bash

I have sth like this :

```
 mysql  --user=$db_user --password=$db_pwd -e"$expQ" | while read name; do
   if [ $name != 'name' ];then
     COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1))
   fi
 done
```

I want to update global counter , but when I executed next query the `COUNTER` does not pick the previous value bcz of the "|" (pipe) .

How I can change the above code to work with named pipes or any other alternative  .
Here is [reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) but I am new to bash and unable to understand if that is possible with mysql 
My bash version says:

`GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) instead, as shown below:

```
COUNTER=0
while read -r name 
do
   if [[ $name != "name" ]]
   then
     ((COUNTER++))
   fi
done < <(mysql  --user="$db_user" --password="$db_pwd" -e"$expQ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 4.2 or later of `bash`, you can also set the `lastpipe` option so that the while loop does not run in a subshell, and the value of `COUNTER` is updated as desired.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
mysql  --user=$db_user --password=$db_pwd -e"$expQ" | while read name; do
  if [ $name != 'name' ];then
    COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1))
  fi
done
```

That said, process substitution is probably still a better idea.

Comment: thanks @chepner , I have bit older version of bash at my disposal